# How to properly import Kotlin's version of ArrayList instead of Java's?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

I just started learning Kotlin and whenever **I try to import an ArrayList like this:**

```
  fun someFunction(){
      var list = ArrayList<String>()
  }
```

It directs me to this class (if I ctrl+click) which seems to me **some kind of linking to the Java version of ArrayList:**

```
@file:Suppress("ACTUAL_WITHOUT_EXPECT") // for building kotlin-stdlib-jvm-minimal-for-test

package kotlin.collections

@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias RandomAccess = java.util.RandomAccess


@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias ArrayList<E> = java.util.ArrayList<E>
@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias LinkedHashMap<K, V> = java.util.LinkedHashMap<K, V>
@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias HashMap<K, V> = java.util.HashMap<K, V>
@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias LinkedHashSet<E> = java.util.LinkedHashSet<E>
@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias HashSet<E> = java.util.HashSet<E>
```

Do I understand this right or am I making a mistake here? `typealias` means whenever I type **ArrayList it actually links to the java.util.ArrayList, no?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `ArrayList` implementation did you expect and what difference would a kotlin version make?

Comment: The one in Collections.kt, or there is none and it actually uses Java's ?

Comment: There is no Kotlin-specific ArrayList on JVM. It truly is just a type alias. I haven't used Kotlin native or Kotlin JS, but I think they use a Kotlin-specific version instead of a type alias.

Answer (score 3):

When you target the JVM platform, Kotlin uses Java's version of `ArrayList` (and many other collection classes). However, this doesn't mean that you're restricted to using only the facilities that Java provides. On the contrary, Kotlin provides many useful extension functions for its collections, irrespective of whether they are typealiases or not.

For example, you can use `indices`:

```
for (i in myList.indices)
    println("$i: $myList[i]")
```

You can even destructure it:

```
val myList = arrayListOf(16, 1, 2023)
val (d, m, y) = myList
```

So you should see the fact that `kotlin.collections.ArrayList` is a typealias of `java.util.ArrayList` as a mere internal implementation detail.

For a full list of capabilities, see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/

Also, if you ctrl+click into ArrayList, IntelliJ is sometimes not very useful in showing you the exact definition of a typealiased class. However, you will see the exact implementation at runtime if you run under the debugger, put a breakpoint on the line where you construct the ArrayList, and then "step into".

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the [Kotlin documentation for `ArrayList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-array-list/) you can see the various type definitions for the different Kotlin platforms - there's one for *Common* (a class), one for *JavaScript* (another class), and one for the *JVM* (Java, which is what you're using):

```
// JVM
typealias ArrayList<E> = ArrayList<E>
```

If you hover over that [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) after the equals, you'll see that it actually is using the `java.util.ArrayList` class. Since it's a `typealias` it means Kotlin's `ArrayList` **on the JVM** is just another name for the `java.util.ArrayList` class.

You can also click on *source* underneath the type definition, which [takes you to the source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/30788566012c571aa1d3590912468d1ebe59983d/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/collections/TypeAliases.kt#L13) (which is what you reached with *ctrl+click*):

```
@SinceKotlin("1.1") public actual typealias ArrayList<E> = java.util.ArrayList<E>
```

So you can see that yeah, on the JVM Kotlin's `ArrayList` is literally just an alias for the Java class. (Viewing the source like this is always useful if you want to know exactly what a class or function in Kotlin is doing!)

But if you view the source for the *Common* and *JS* implementations, you'll see they're implemented differently. So what you're actually using in the end depends on which platform your Kotlin code is being compiled against.

Answer (score 1):

`typealias` provides alternative names for existing types, [type aliases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html) do not introduce new types. They are **equivalent** to the corresponding underlying types

Essentially, there is only one version of `ArrayList`, that's `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: So Kotlin actually uses the Java's ArrayList?